# How to make firefox report the javascript error?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firebug

I am developing with Firefox and Firebug, but in my environment if the js has the syntax error, the firefox will not report any error, it just stops there.

Then I have to use IE to reload the page, IE will report the error at the bottom left corner, and after clicking it I can see the line number of the js error.

I am wondering if I misconfigured something? I think at least firebug should report the error as IE does. But firebug displayed nothing.

The example code(show error in IE but normal in FF):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  body { color:blue; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    if (a < ) 0 {
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To configure Firebug to show errors, do the following:

- Click the arrow on the Console tab.
- Make sure it's Enabled.
- Make sure "Show JavaScript Errors" is checked.

You should see the errors in the console now, and it should show you the line number and filename.

I am using Firefox 3.6 and Firebug 1.5.0.

**UPDATE:** This same process also works in the latest Firefox Nightly 19.0a1, using Firebug 1.10.4. Thus, these instructions are still up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may enable the 'Script' option. With this option on, while a js error occurs, firefox stops caused by the breakpoint of js source where error occurs.